# Handling events of Application.Resources where they are used

Tags: wpf, user-controls, datatemplate

I have `Button` inside application.resources `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="contactItem" DataType="{x:Type Model:Contact}">
<Button x:Name="openButton" Style="{StaticResource openButton}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

How can I handle `openButton` click in `UserControl`?

```
<ItemsControl ItemSource="{Binding CurrentContacts}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource contactItem}">
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `ButtonBase.Click` handler to `ItemsControl`.

```
 <ItemsControl ButtonBase.Click="MyItemsControl_Click">
  </ItemsControl>
```

Inside that event handler's code you can use the `DataContext` property of `e.OriginalSource` (it should be of type `Button`) to access data bound object.

```
private void MyItemsControl_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var myDataObject = ((Button)e.OriginalSource).DataContext;
}
```

Comment: Right, that's what event routing is for after all.